# Manipulating database objects on a web canvas

Tags: javascript, sql, database, web, cad

I'm trying to find the right way in order to solve this problem.
Manipulate database objects using a web canvas.
The idea here is to come up with something similar (but in simplified form) to the Enovia VPM web portal, where you can see SQL objects, in the form of a box, containing some attributes (like part number, status) and of course those attributes they belong to a specific row in a sql database.
I can't find the code to base my approach to scaling on a proper solution.

I don't have an idea to start this. I know most of the best solutions could come from JavaScript. I found some examples where you can manipulate (pan, zoom, click) "frozen" images, but I'm not sure how to implement this with an SQL interface.

Here a nice example:

https://codepen.io/chengarda/pen/wRxoyB

```
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

let cameraOffset = { x: window.innerWidth / 2, y: window.innerHeight / 2 };
let cameraZoom = 1;
let MAX_ZOOM = 5;
let MIN_ZOOM = 0.1;
let SCROLL_SENSITIVITY = 0.0005;

function draw() {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    // Translate to the canvas centre before zooming - so you'll always zoom on what you're looking directly at
    ctx.translate(window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2);
    ctx.scale(cameraZoom, cameraZoom);
    ctx.translate(
        -window.innerWidth / 2 + cameraOffset.x,
        -window.innerHeight / 2 + cameraOffset.y
    );
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#991111";
    drawRect(-50, -50, 100, 100);

    ctx.fillStyle = "#eecc77";
    drawRect(-35, -35, 20, 20);
    drawRect(15, -35, 20, 20);
    drawRect(-35, 15, 70, 20);

    ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
    drawText("Simple Pan and Zoom Canvas", -255, -100, 32, "courier");

    ctx.rotate((-31 * Math.PI) / 180);
    ctx.fillStyle = `#${(Math.round(Date.now() / 40) % 4096).toString(16)}`;
    drawText("Now with touch!", -110, 100, 32, "courier");

    ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
    ctx.rotate((31 * Math.PI) / 180);

    drawText("Wow, you found me!", -260, -2000, 48, "courier");

    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

// Gets the relevant location from a mouse or single touch event
function getEventLocation(e) {
    if (e.touches && e.touches.length == 1) {
        return { x: e.touches[0].clientX, y: e.touches[0].clientY };
    } else if (e.clientX && e.clientY) {
        return { x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY };
    }
}

function drawRect(x, y, width, height) {
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
}

function drawText(text, x, y, size, font) {
    ctx.font = `${size}px ${font}`;
    ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
}

let isDragging = false;
let dragStart = { x: 0, y: 0 };

function onPointerDown(e) {
    isDragging = true;
    dragStart.x = getEventLocation(e).x / cameraZoom - cameraOffset.x;
    dragStart.y = getEventLocation(e).y / cameraZoom - cameraOffset.y;
}

function onPointerUp(e) {
    isDragging = false;
    initialPinchDistance = null;
    lastZoom = cameraZoom;
}

function onPointerMove(e) {
    if (isDragging) {
        cameraOffset.x = getEventLocation(e).x / cameraZoom - dragStart.x;
        cameraOffset.y = getEventLocation(e).y / cameraZoom - dragStart.y;
    }
}

function handleTouch(e, singleTouchHandler) {
    if (e.touches.length == 1) {
        singleTouchHandler(e);
    } else if (e.type == "touchmove" && e.touches.length == 2) {
        isDragging = false;
        handlePinch(e);
    }
}

let initialPinchDistance = null;
let lastZoom = cameraZoom;

function handlePinch(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let touch1 = { x: e.touches[0].clientX, y: e.touches[0].clientY };
    let touch2 = { x: e.touches[1].clientX, y: e.touches[1].clientY };

    // This is distance squared, but no need for an expensive sqrt as it's only used in ratio
    let currentDistance =
        (touch1.x - touch2.x) ** 2 + (touch1.y - touch2.y) ** 2;

    if (initialPinchDistance == null) {
        initialPinchDistance = currentDistance;
    } else {
        adjustZoom(null, currentDistance / initialPinchDistance);
    }
}

function adjustZoom(zoomAmount, zoomFactor) {
    if (!isDragging) {
        if (zoomAmount) {
            cameraZoom += zoomAmount;
        } else if (zoomFactor) {
            console.log(zoomFactor);
            cameraZoom = zoomFactor * lastZoom;
        }

        cameraZoom = Math.min(cameraZoom, MAX_ZOOM);
        cameraZoom = Math.max(cameraZoom, MIN_ZOOM);

        console.log(zoomAmount);
    }
}

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", onPointerDown);
canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", (e) => handleTouch(e, onPointerDown));
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", onPointerUp);
canvas.addEventListener("touchend", (e) => handleTouch(e, onPointerUp));
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", onPointerMove);
canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", (e) => handleTouch(e, onPointerMove));
canvas.addEventListener("wheel", (e) =>
    adjustZoom(e.deltaY * SCROLL_SENSITIVITY)
);

// Ready, set, go
draw();
```

(Imagine instead of that square face, a box with information given from a database)